# Why are my vertex points under the icing?

Tags: vertices

another noob here asking for help. When i want to apply the drip effect to the icing, the vertex points are under the icing. This is my second donut project, but this didnt happened before.

can someone help me pls?[image]

Comment: I haven't looked at that tutorial for a long time. but is the Thickness value in the Solidify modifier a negative or positive value?

Comment: @JohnEason There's a 3.0 version of the tutorial.  The drip effect is new to that version, fwiw.  I think it's proportional editing but I've not watched that tutorial either.

Comment: My guess is that you're in Edit mode and you've enabled "Edit Mode Visibility" (blue square next to modifier name in modifiers properties panel) for the solidify and subdiv modifiers which ... shows the effect of the modifiers in edit mode...

Comment: @Marty Fouts Actually I've just looked at that part of his (3.0) tutorial and at 1:08 in part 4 of the tutorial, Andrew specifically tells you to uncheck the Edit Mode icon in the Solidify modifier which of course makes the vertices visible.